# How to get multiple pages and different size(portrait , landscape) with Dompdf

Tags: php, html, dompdf, laravel-dompdf

I have six html pages in the single html file and ı want to convert to pdf with dompdf like below;

1. page size landscape,
2. page size landscape,
3. page size landscape,
4. page size portrait,
5. page size portrait,
6. page size portrait

how can I do?

I have six html pages in the single html file and ı want to convert to pdf with dompdf

Answer (score 1):

Use Composer to install dompdf.

```
composer require dompdf/dompdf
```

Create a new PHP file, name it convert.php, and include the dompdf library.

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
```

Instantiate the Dompdf class.

```
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
```

Set the paper size and orientation for each HTML page.

```
$pages = [
    ['html' => 'sayfa1.html', 'size' => 'landscape'],
    ['html' => 'sayfa2.html', 'size' => 'landscape'],
    ['html' => 'sayfa3.html', 'size' => 'landscape'],
    ['html' => 'sayfa4.html', 'size' => 'portrait'],
    ['html' => 'sayfa5.html', 'size' => 'portrait'],
    ['html' => 'sayfa6.html', 'size' => 'portrait']
];

foreach ($pages as $page) {
    $dompdf->set_paper($page['size']);
    $html = file_get_contents($page['html']);
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->render();
}
```

PDF File saves.

```
$dompdf->stream('cikti.pdf', ['Attachment' => false]);
```

Run the script by executing the following command in the terminal.

```
php convert.php
```

Hello.

Update :)

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

$dompdf = new Dompdf();

$pages = [
    ['html' => 'sayfa1.html', 'size' => 'landscape'],
    ['html' => 'sayfa2.html', 'size' => 'landscape'],
    ['html' => 'sayfa3.html', 'size' => 'landscape'],
    ['html' => 'sayfa4.html', 'size' => 'portrait'],
    ['html' => 'sayfa5.html', 'size' => 'portrait'],
    ['html' => 'sayfa6.html', 'size' => 'portrait']
];

foreach ($pages as $page) {
    $dompdf->setPaper('A4', $page['size']);
    $html = file_get_contents($page['html']);

    // HTML Sayfasında php etiketi var ise kaldıralım.
    $html = preg_replace('/<\?php.*?\?>/s', '', $html);

    $dompdf->loadHtml($html);
    $dompdf->render();

    $outputFilename = basename($page['html'], '.html') . '.pdf';
    file_put_contents($outputFilename, $dompdf->output());
}
```

Make sure you have the files like sayfa1.html in the directory where the page is located, then when you run php convert.php in the terminal, you can generate a PDF file for each HTML page.

Sorry google translate :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have 6 pages in the php page that I want to print as a pdf.<body> <!--First Page--> <div class="container"> first page</div> <!--Second Page--> <div class="container"> second page</div> .... My php page is like this

Comment: @CihanYıldız I have updated the comment, could you please try the code in the comment again? I have adapted it to PHP.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have 6 pages in the php page that I want to print as a pdf.<body> <!--First Page--> <div class="container"> first page</div> <!--Second Page--> <div class="container"> second page</div> .... My php page is like this

Comment: Can we download all these pdf files as a single pdf file after viewing it in the browser?